# async await for a simple wrapper method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

If I write a method that is just wrapping an async method such as this:

```
public async Task WrapMethodAsync()
{
    using(var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        await smtpClient.SendMailAysnc(new MailMessage());
    }
}
```

Is that the same as doing the following:

```
public Task WrapMethodAsync()
{
    using(var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        return smtpClient.SendMailAysnc(new MailMessage());
    }
}
```

Or is the latter not actually running asynchronously?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate. The answer is "mostly" - the difference being that if an exception is thrown by the `SmtpClient` constructor (or the `MailMessage` constructor, or the start of the `SendMailAsync` method), in the first case you'll get a faulted task; in the second case you'll get an exception straight away.

Comment: It's probably a duplicate, but for the life of me I didn't know what to search by.

Comment: Understood. Hopefully someone else will find one.

Comment: Search for "C# await tutorial". This is so basic that you must be able to answer this yourself. If you don't know the answer to this question using async programming is quite dangerous.

Comment: @JonSkeet The semantics of disposing the client are far more important than the exception handling semantics.

Comment: @Servy: Eek, you're absolutely right - missed that entirely!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this exact scenario the two cases are **extremely different** because of the `using` scope.

In the first case you wait (asynchronously) for the `SendMailAysnc` operation to complete before disposing of the client while in the other case you don't so you would **dispose of the client while the operation is still running**.

In the general case where there isn't a difference in the general behavior. For example this:

```
public async Task Run()
{
    throw new Exception("stored");
    await Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

VS this:

```
public Task Run()
{
    throw new Exception("thrown");
    return Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

The difference is that the `async` method has a *slight* overhead of the whole `async` mechanism (including a state machine) while the non-`async` task-returning method has a different exception semantics as exceptions are **thrown directly and not stored in the returned task**.

Answer (score 4):

The first snippet disposes of the client after the mail is sent, the latter disposes of the client after it *starts* sending the mail, but before it has finished.  Assuming the client isn't supposed to be disposed while it is sending messages, it means that the first solution is very problematic.

Additionally, the error handling semantics are different; exceptions in constructing the `Task` in the first snippet will result in the method throwing an exception, whereas in the second snippet they result in the return task being marked as `Faulted` with the appropriate exception set.